# JSOUP Проверка наличия тега в блоке

Tags: kotlin, jsoup

Есть `<div class="item">` в нём `<div class="item_name">` в нем `<span class="item_name_creator">`

Парсится вот так и добавляется в список.

```
val elements = document.select("div[class=item]")
for (i in 0 until elements.size) {
                val title = elements.select("div[class=item_name]")
                    .select("div>span")
                    .eq(i)
                    .text()
                    }
```

Проблема в том, что если span.item_name_creator отсутствует, то список сдвигается. Как сделать проверку на наличие span в блоке и при его отсутствии дописывать title = "unknown"? Спасибо.

Comment: Cелектор title можно сделать так "div.item_name span.item_name_creator", а дальше в конце сделать проверку isNotEmpty()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так, если я правильно понял, что вам нужно получить:

```
document.select("div[class=item]>div[class=item_name]")
    .forEach { itemName ->
        val title = itemName.select("span[class=item_name_creator]").text()
        println(if (title.isNotEmpty()) title else "unknown") //заменить на добавление в список
    }
```